# Combining and cleaning up data in Excel vba, Works but looking for potential cleanup, 5 minute run-time

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a project to combine data from multiple workbooks within a folder, pull out the information that I need (LC, Part #, Estimated Ship Date), and then display that data in a pivot table.

The table is fine but the pulling of information is taking quite a while and I was hoping someone may be able to help me clean up the code or even introduce me to functions I may not know about that are faster.  It has been a while since I've coded anything so I do apologize if I'm doing things very poorly.

I'll post each sub with a description of what it is doing.

Populate_Data: This sub is calling all of the other Subs, as well as pulling in the first worksheet from all of the files in a folder location.

```
Sub Populate_Data()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Call Delete Sheets to clean up any old data
Delete_Sheets

'Set the File Path to pull Files from
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim intCurrentColumn As Integer

intCurrentColumn = 1

FolderPath = "P:\RNL\Expedite Reports - Incoming\"
Filename = Dir(FolderPath + "*.xls*")

'Loop through and copy the first sheet from each workbook
Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
        Sheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()
Loop

'Create Loop for gathering and copying Data
Dim intSheetCount, intCurrentCount As Integer
intSheetCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

For intCurrentCount = 3 To intSheetCount

    Sheets(intCurrentCount).Activate
    Collect_Data (intCurrentColumn)
    Append_Data (intCurrentColumn)
    intCurrentColumn = intCurrentColumn + 3

Next intCurrentCount

'Call Clean Parts to clean up the Parts worksheet
Clean_Parts

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Delete_Sheets: This deletes all excess sheets, as well as cleaning up the Parts Worksheet of any data it still has.

```
Sub Delete_Sheets()

'Deletes all sheets except specified sheets using codenames
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Select Case ws.CodeName
    Case "Master", "Parts"
            Case Else
        ws.Delete
    End Select
Next

'Clean up Parts Sheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Collect Data: This is the one I'm guessing could use the most cleanup/a better method? This pulls the relevant data from each worksheet and places it into groups of 3 columns on the Parts worksheet.  The data I am given is not consistent enough to use an offset or anything to determine where the data may be on a sheet, so it is searched by headers.

```
Sub Collect_Data(intCurrentColumn As Integer)

Dim PartsWs As Worksheet
Set PartsWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

Dim CellRange As Range
Dim NextRow As Integer

Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
Set ThisSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

'Look to Simplify This
'Search the Current Active Sheet
With ThisSheet

    'LC
    Set CellRange = .Rows(1).Find(What:="LC", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not CellRange Is Nothing Then
        CellRange.EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=PartsWs.Columns(intCurrentColumn)
    End If

    'Part Num
    Set CellRange = .Rows(1).Find(What:="Part Num", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not CellRange Is Nothing Then
        CellRange.EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=PartsWs.Columns(intCurrentColumn + 1)
    End If

    'Estimated Ship Date
    Set CellRange = .Rows(1).Find(What:="Estimated Ship Date*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not CellRange Is Nothing Then
        CellRange.EntireColumn.Copy 
Destination:=PartsWs.Columns(intCurrentColumn + 2)
    End If
End With
'This Section End

End Sub
```

Append Data: This is used to append the data from the columns on the Parts sheet into the first three columns, essentially just making the data a list.

```
Sub Append_Data(intCurrentColumn)

Dim PartsWs As Worksheet
Set PartsWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

Dim CopyRange As Range
Dim lngLastRow, lngLastPartsA As Long

'Get the last rows in column A and the column we are starting the range from
lngLastPartsA = PartsWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lngLastRow = PartsWs.Cells(Rows.Count, intCurrentColumn).End(xlUp).Row

'Set range to copy
With PartsWs
    Set CopyRange = .Range(.Cells(2, intCurrentColumn), .Cells(lngLastRow, intCurrentColumn + 2))
End With

'Copy range after data already in Column A
CopyRange.Copy (PartsWs.Cells(lngLastPartsA + 1, 1))

End Sub
```

Lastly, Clean Parts:  This simply cleans up the parts worksheet of any rows that have no information in the Estimated Shipping Date Column, as well as cleaning up all the rest of the extra columns once I've moved all the data.

```
Sub Clean_Parts()

Dim PartsWs As Worksheet
Set PartsWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

Dim intCount As Integer
Dim lngColumnCount, lngLastRow As Long

lngColumnCount = PartsWs.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For intCount = 4 To lngColumnCount

    PartsWs.Columns(4).EntireColumn.Delete

Next intCount

lngLastRow = PartsWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For intCount = 2 To lngLastRow

    If IsEmpty(PartsWs.Cells(intCount, 3)) Then

        PartsWs.Rows(intCount).EntireRow.Delete
        intCount = intCount - 1

    End If

Next intCount

End Sub
```

If any of this is too vague, or if I need to re-post a smaller/more direct question then please simply let me know.  I appreciate any help!

EDIT: Upon further testing, the pulling and parsing of info is only taking about 2 minutes (still a long time), which means that my cleanup is taking the rest of the time.  I'm currently looking into other methods to hasten cleanup but i'm open to ideas still.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about working code belong on Code Review not Stack Overflow.  But please review their what to ask before posting

Comment: That's an awfully long post to expect people to read through.  Is this your code?  If so, you must have some idea which part is taking the most time? Also, how much data are you talking about?  Is this a one time thing?  have you tried any of Excel's built-in tools for combining data?  Please see [help/on-topic] as well as [mcve].

Comment: My apologies I was not aware of Code Review, I shall move my question there.  Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

If all the files are on a network drive, that may be bogging it down... perhaps you could copy them to your C: drive first?

Comment: The goal is for anyone on the sales team to be able to run this when they need to lookup when we are expecting a part in so unfortunately I don't believe moving the files is an option.

Comment: Perhaps it should be done automatically (somehow) on a daily / hourly basis so that the user doesn't have to wait (other than for an update)?

Comment: I was just considering that as an option after I typed this actually.

Comment: An answer should provide clear direction, examples, links and more. (see [answer].)

Comment: It wasn't exactly presented as in-scope for the question, but the OP confirms it was in-scope for his/her issue.  "Faster" is open-ended, I think.

Answer (score -1):

Any process will run faster on your C-drive rather than your corporate network drive.  Also, to do all the aggregation, download and install the AddIn from the link below.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

[image]